# AndEngine TMX performance

Tags: andengine, tmx

The performance of displaying TMX maps in AndEngine is poor. Is there any chance of speeding it up? TMXLayer.draw() draws each tile separately. Any chance of putting multiple TMX tiles to a single vertex buffer and drawing them all at once? If so, could someone show some (pseudo) code please?